# How to check whether a dropdown is selected or search button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire ajax on dropdown change or search button is clicked (not on change of words). How can I check it in one go becuase I don't want to check it seperately.

For example - If I had to check on change of dropdown and on change of search input, I would use the following script

```
jQuery(function($){
 
    jQuery( ".js-category, .js-input" ).on( "change", function() {
        
    });
 
});
```

But I want to check on either dropdown is changed or search button is pressed and I want to check it one go.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and cleanest would probably be using a named function. Then register the function as callback of two separate events.

```js
function eventHandler(event) {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}

jQuery("#dropdown").on("change", eventHandler);
jQuery("#button").on("click", eventHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dropdown">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>

<button id="button" type="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <select id="select">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<button id="button" type="button">click me</button>

<script>
    $('#button, #select').on('click change', function(e) {
      if(e.type==='change' && this.id =='select' || e.type==='click' && this.id =='button') {
    alert('select');
  }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: In both the condition the same function is going to run, that's why I wanted to check it one go. I mean if the dropdown is changed, still I will check both the values ie dropdown and if the search button is checked still I will do the same activity.

Comment: ok, i updated the code you can check it in single condition

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap dropdown and button into the form and listen for submit (search button was clicked) and for change (dropdown selection was changed) events. Don't forget to prevent default submit behaviour in order to avoid unwanted redirections.

```js
$("#js-form").on("change submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  $("#test").html($("#test").html() + 0)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="js-form">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="test">0</div>
```